# How to use MonoTouch.Dialog's ActivityElement?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I might be missing something here, but this code:

```
this.oSectionDRs = new Section()
{
    new ActivityElement()
    {
        Caption = Locale.GetLocale("Settings_Loading"), 
        Animating = true
    }
};

// To begin with just show a loading indicator.
this.Root = new RootElement (Locale.GetLocale("Settings_Select"))
{
    this.oSectionDRs
};
```

Does not show any animated thingy. It is showing the label only. How can I get the animated star?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code:

```
var root = new RootElement("foo");
      root.Add (new Section("foo", "bar") {
      new ActivityElement()
      {
        Caption = "foo",
        Animating = true
      }
    });

    var dvc = new DialogViewController(root, false);


    window.RootViewController = dvc;
```

I get both the caption and the activity scroller thing. Not sure it helps you tho! I was just using the built in MT.D.

Comment: The problem is that ActivityElement has never been adjusted to work with popovers. It is using UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds to calculate its location. That's why it is working for you if it is the root controller. I have an example of a fixed version that solves the problem: https://github.com/Krumelur/ReviewSelection/blob/master/ReviewSelection/UI/Elements/FixedActivityElement.cs

Comment: Ah yes. You'd need to change it to now use Bounds - there are a few bits in MT.D that assume fullscreen and fail on the iPad.